# How to sample for success/failure from small populations and probabilities

Tags: sampling, error, population

I am interested in sampling data that comes in a yes/no form. A couple things I would like help in understanding. Why does the reasonable sample size change when my population shrinks? We might be talking populations of 200. In what I think is a related issue, how do I handle the fact that the distribution of yes to no might be 95 to 5? Is it possible to do useful things and give good confidence/error values for this situation? Maybe just numerically?

Thank you!

Comment: Although I'm not sure what you mean by "reasonable" sample size, it seems to me that if you find, say, a sample size of 1000 for a national opinion poll to be "reasonable," then it would *a fortiori* be obvious that a reasonable sample size for your population of 200 *must* be smaller than that!

Comment: I should have specified what I meant my reasonable. Basically for a given confidence and error value. I have read some about hypergeometric distributions. I guess I don't fundamentally understand why the fact that there are 50 unsampled individuals, as opposed to 5000, would change how many confident you are in your results?